# How Do I Set The Current Date In A Material-UI TextField

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

If I set `type="date"` on a `TextField` I can initialise it with a string.

https://codesandbox.io/s/9y6yz462op

```
const values = {
  someDate: "2017-05-24"
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField
        name="someDate"
        label="Some Date"
        InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true, required: true }}
        type="date"
        defaultValue={values.someDate}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, when I try to use the current date using a date object

```
const values = {
  someDate: new Date()
};
```

I get an error

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `defaultValue` supplied to `TextField`.
```

How do I pass a Date to the TextField?

Comment: Possibly because `defaultValue` is not a `prop` to `TextField` in material-ui. Do check in their documentation for available props.

Comment: @VikasYadav `TextField` does have the `defaultValue` as property as you can see in [the docs](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#props)

Comment: ok. but I suppose `defaultValue` has `union: string |
 number` as prop type. It is not `object` type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read in [the docs](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#props) `defaultValue` has to be either a `string` or a `number`. The `Date` type is not supported.

But since you're using `type="date"` you should be fine by handing the date as string.

e.g.

```
const values = {
  someDate: new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);
};
```